# Checking if variable is set in global scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, closures, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to check if a JavaScript variable has been set in the global scope in your code? Here's the use case:

```
var pizza;

pizza.isGlobalScoped()
```

Is there some method/conditional or any other way to figure out if a variable is not block scoped or within a closure?

Comment: Since you added the `reactjs` tag, define global.

Comment: Well, all variables that are block scoped are known statically, so that's not particularly interesting…

Comment: Why is this tagged with ECMAScript 6?

Comment: Look at the comment further down :)

Answer (score 3):

In the browser you can do

```
If ( "pizza" in window)...
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you're out of "strict" mode, you can declare a variable as such:

```
thing = 'hello world';

console.log(window.thing); // => 'hello world';
```

Other than that, there is no way to determine the scope of a variables unless you query some object it's attached to.

Comment: That's not a *declaration*.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to define variables in the global scope without it actually mounting it in the global namespace. Eventually this would lead us  to declare variables in the global context and pass them to the target scope without having to declare within the local scope.

Comment: --- > ({a, b} = {a: {}, b: {} }); after that we could use a method or something on the variable and it mounts to your block scoped function/whatever